# Can cum be used with living beings?

Tags: word-usage

The meaning of cum is 
combined with; also used as (used to describe things with a dual nature or function).

For example a sofa cum bed

Can it be used with humans as well like

My friend cum brother?

Comment: Use of *cum* outside of academic circles will be viewed as pretentious, and may not be understood at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that Google Books has 1190 written instances of [*sofa **cum** bed*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sofa%20cum%20bed%22), but it also has 343 instances of [*sofa **come** bed*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sofa%20come%20bed%22), which makes a lot more sense to me.

As you might expect, the formal Latin ***cum*** (meaning ***with***) is particularly used in academic contexts - such as *[to graduate]* [***cum laude***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cum_laude) = ***with*** honour(s).

There's an orthographic quirk whereby *to **come** [to a sexual climax]* has led to the unusual *noun* spelling ***cum*** = ejaculate (though the *verb* form is usually still written as *I'm coming!, Did you come?*, not *I'm cumming!, Did you cum?*). So it's possible some "non-academically-inclined" readers might primarily associate the quirky spelling with sexual overtones, not the Latin origin. But one shouldn't pay too much attention to such "snigger potential" (it would often be considered "childish" to even acknowledge it, let alone laugh oneself).

My personal choice would be to write about *my friend-come-brother*. Which I interpret as a "reduced" form of, say, *my friend **who can become** my brother [in appropriate circumstances]*.

This distinction only applies in *speech*, obviously. And I'd hazard a guess that the *majority* of native Anglophones might not even realise that the majority of *published writers* use the ***cum*** spelling in this construction (because they don't know that spelling *at all*; most natives Anglophones aren't as knowledgeable about orthography, academia, and Latin roots as most published writers/editors).

---

As regards OP's specific question (can this construction be used of *people?*), the answer is it's a complete non-issue. Of course you can.

Comment: My friend-cum-brother means my friend as well as my brother

Comment: Erm... Who's teaching who here? In any context I can imagine, *my friend-cum-brother* means *my friend **who also fulfils the role of "brother"***. That sequence would only normally be used when the friend isn't actually the speaker's *biological* brother (if he *were*, the more likely sequence would be *my brother-come-friend*).

Comment: Yeah. It would be brother cum friend if he was my biological brother

Comment: But friend cum brother means someone who is my friend as well as like a brother to me.   I dont know why all these sayin it aint idiomatic

Comment: Among users of American English, "friend-come-brother" would simply not be understood at all in speech. In writing, sufficiently educated readers would view it as a gross mistake for "friend-cum-brother." Nevertheless, I am not going to down vote this answer because I do not know British English sufficiently well to comment on what is definitely not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

In American English, "brother" is often used as a synonym for "male friend." If it is intended to make clear that a male is a very close friend but not technically a brother by blood or adoption, a phrase similar to "my friend, who is as close to me as a brother" would be used.

The use of "cum," pronounced "coom," is rare in American English and virtually absent outside academic or quasi-academic discourse. The use of "cum," pronounced like the verb "come," in the sense that you are describing is simply not heard in American speech. For example, the common American term is "sofa-bed," not "sofa cum bed" or "sofa come bed."

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why "cum" can't be used for humans, to indicate two separate roles combined in one person:

> I have a chauffeur cum gardener in my employ.

Aside: many place names in the UK use it to indicate two parishes combined as one, such as [Shingay-cum-Wendy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingay_cum_Wendy) and it is not always hyphenated. It has the same usage as in the question.

Similarly please see the usage in [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cum) for "study-cum-bedroom."